# Swipe on Kobiton device using selenium

Tags: android, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to swipe left to right on my mobile automation testing.

I am using a selenium framework to open the mobile devices on `Kobiton` but can't seem to find a way to swipe the screen.

I have tried to use:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("('element').trigger('swipe', {startX: 0.95})");
```

which I found from another ticket but it doesn't work. Is there a way to swipe an element in selenium or is there some other way to swipe?

If more information is needed I'm happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Try to create an action
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

//get location start
int startY = element1.getLocation().getY() + (element1.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
int startX = element1.getLocation().getX() + (element1.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

//get location end
int endX = element2.getLocation().getX() + (element2.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
int endY = element2.getLocation().getY() + (element2.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

//and execute the action
action.press(startX, startY).waitAction(2000).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```